# How to read a table which is saved by saveAsTable in Apache Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, hive-table

I am trying to save a dataframe by using `df.write.saveAsTable("table_name")`

but i am unable to retrieve this table again (not in the same run).

I tried

```
spark.read.table("table_name")
```

and

```
spark.sql("select * from table_name")
```

but both didn't worked give error

```
 Table or view not found: table_name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example:

`df.write.saveAsTable('table_name')`

`df = spark.table('table_name')`